# How to make C++ Mysql Connector work with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to made a database application with C++ and MySQL, on Microsoft Studio 2019.
I just discovered that MSVS 2019 might not work with the most recent version of the C++ Mysql connector ( Version 8.0.17)

I'm trying to make the program work using the example from this page:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/jdbc_ref.html

I expected it to work fine, but I got a bad_alloc error, and couldn't find any explanation to it.

EDIT: By the way, that's the line that MSVS says that is throwing the error:

```cpp
boost::scoped_ptr< sql::Connection >
            con(driver->connect(url, user, pass));
```

Comment: i didn't try it with 2019 but try this step by step  guide https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-notes.html

Comment: That's what I followed to get there, but it still doesn't work.
Visual Studio tells me there was an unhandled exception and tells me it was this kind of exception.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the "Solution Configuration" to Release instead of Debug, worked for me...